# How to pass `option-c` to Hyper terminal rather than `ç`?

Tags: terminal, keybindings, macos

I'm trying to get the fzf directory switcher to work in my terminal (Hyper).

It is supposed to work using `option-c` but in my case that just enters a cedille (`ç`).

[One workaround I found](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/164) is to use `Esc-c` instead.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a “meta” or “alt” modifier, which Mac doesn't have natively. Hyper (like most Mac terminal emulators) can be configured to use the <kbd>⌥option</kbd> or <kbd>⌘command</kbd> key as a meta key. Open the [configuration file](https://hyper.is/#config-location) (you can do this from Hyper with the “Hyper” > “Preferences” menu entry). There, look for the `config: { … }` block. If there isn't already one, add a nested `modifierKeys` block. To make <kbd>⌥option</kbd> act as a meta modifier in Hyper instead of having its usual “alternative character” meaning, set the `altIsMeta` boolean option.

```
"use strict";
// Future versions of Hyper may add additional config options,
// which will not automatically be merged into this file.
// See https://hyper.is#cfg for all currently supported options.
module.exports = {
    config: {
        modifierKeys: {
            altIsMeta: true,
        },
        …
    },
    …
};
```

Hyper has a [bug whereby this doesn't work correctly for dead keys](https://github.com/vercel/hyper/issues/6337#issuecomment-1160814584). For example, with a US keyboard, this makes <kbd>⌥+c</kbd> equivalent to <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>, but <kbd>⌥+e</kbd> keeps its dead key function in addition to its Meta+E function, so <kbd>⌥+e</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> is equivalent to Meta+E and then inserting á.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! I've linked to this Q&A from the respective issue as it perfectly explains the issue for Hyper users who may account that issue instead: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/164